# C++/CLI converting from a String^ to array <Byte>

Tags: string, c++-cli, arrays

I have a serial port application which is written C++/CLI

To read data from the ports input buffer I am using

```
String^ inputString = System::IO:Ports::SerialPort::ReadExisting();
```

I need to convert the inputString value to an array of bytes. I have tried using

```
array<Byte> ^unicodeBytes = System::Text::Encoding::Unicode->GetBytes( inputString );
```

This works so long as the value being read in to my port input buffer is less than 0x7F (hex). Any values greater than `0x7F` gets converted to `0x3F` = "?"

E.g. if I send two bytes comprising `{0x7F, 0xFF}` to my input port then when I read and convert them the array `unicodeBytes = { 0x7F 0x00, 0x3F 0x00}` when looked at in the debugger watch window of VS2008

According to the unicode tables I have looked at OxFF is a valid unicode value equal to a latin small letter 'y' with two small dots above it.

Any suggestins on how to convert 'y' with two samll dots = 0xFF in string format to 0xFF in a byte array would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use the `ASCII` (or another codepage) encoding, not `Unicode` :)

Comment: If your goal is to read bytes (binary data), then don't use an API that reads strings. Try using the Read method that takes a byte array instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549.aspx

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. Reading in the binary data is exactly what I am trying to do so I have deployed the Read method and its all working now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SerialPort`'s `Read` method to get bytes instead of decoding encoded text:

```
int BufferSize = <some size>;
array<byte> ^bytes = gcnew array<byte>(BufferSize);
int available = serialPort->BytesAvailable;
serialPort->Read(bytes, 0, Math::Min(available, BufferSize));
```